# Compressing or Trimming fonts for font-face usage

Tags: fonts, font-face

I'm starting work on an web project which will an [Urdu language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu) font, specifically using Jameel Nastaleeq font. I have been looking into using either Cufon or @font-face.

The font is fine for local installation, however, it's huge for any practical web usage.

Sizes:

```
TTF  - 13   MB
EOT  - 13.5 MB
SVG  - 33   KB
WOFF -  8.7 MB
```

Due to the size, only [Code And More](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/) was even able to generate the font-face kit. Others, such as [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) flatly refused to work with a font file this big.

Is there any easy way for me to "trim" the original TTF font so that I only have the unicode range I need. Or compress the actual font so that the online generators can handle it properly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure there is a way to do this using fontsquirrel's online webfont generator.  Try uploading your fonts and selecting the "advanced" option.  Again, I'm not entirely sure it's there, but if it is then that's the easiest way to do it.  The only other way that I know of would be to use a program that can manipulate fonts.  The only reputable and free program that does this that I know of is inkscape.  To do this I believe you would need the font in svg format which you could get using fontsquirrel. The inkscape method might not be worth the effort depending on how badly you need this done, but those are the only two ways I know how to do it.

Edit:
sorry I didn't see your note about fontsquirrel.  If you really need this done try to find another way to get an svg file and use inkscape